# Common html file should be included in index.html

Tags: html, angularjs

I have an angularjs web app with multiple views and controllers.I have a html file named topnav.html which is included in all the views except for 3.Instead of including it in all views , i want to include it in just index.html . I will get it in all the views if I do that. I have to exclude it from 3 specific views. How do I do that?

```
div class="container p-t-md" >
<div ng-include="'views/topnav.html'"></div>
<div class="row">
    <div ng-include="'views/leftpanel.html'"></div>
```

I include that topnav.html in all the views except 3. Instead I want into include it only in index.html .But the problem is I'm getting that topnav.html in all the views including the 3 views .but, I don't want topnav.html to be included in some 3 of my views.
I know i have to use ng-if but I don't know what to put in it.

Comment: The description is not clear enough. Please provide an example.

Comment: @JFMeier Was this edit clear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an ng-if to accomplish excluding that reference on a specific page. You need to provide a better example of what you are trying to do.

Create a variable that persists through all of your pages like so:

```
//Make this a universal variable
$scope.includeJS = true;

 //Put this either in the js of the page you want to not have the reference or put it in a universal js and put a $watch on it.
if($location.path() == "/ExcludePath")
{
    //if it is in a universal js
   $scope.includeJS = false;

   // if it is in a js file outside a universal js
   $scope.$parent.universalCtrl.includeJS = false;
}
```

Comment: Yes , but I can't figure out what to put in ng-if. I don't want that to be included in my login.html code. Is there a way to get url path and put it in ng-if or ng-hide?

Comment: Are you using routing?

Comment: I updated my post take a look. You need to have a JS file that is persisted across all of your pages, or you can use the javascript for the page in question and when that JS loads use the code above to exclude the file you want to exclude

Comment: Anytime, make sure you include $location into your controllers to!

Answer (score 0):

You can create an AppController that handles high level decisions. In there you put the logic that you need to show your top nav.

Your index page would look something like this:

```
<body ng-controller="AppController">
    <div ng-if="showTopNav()" ng-include="'views/topnav.html'"></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</body>
```

and inside the AppController:

```
$scope.showTopNav = function () {
    var result;
    //logic to show top nav...
    return result;
}
```